# Opening a ZIP file, scanning a CSV file inside it and transferring certain content to another CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The following code views the CSV file inside the ZIP folder and then using the concept of index setting, tries to extract the row containing the entry "HINDUNILVR" in the column "SYMBOL", of each and every CSV file (this code segment is inside another loop) , for a series of dates (read ZIP FILES). However, there is some problem in the code, as the there is no output in my "stock.csv" file that is present in C: . It is empty after running this code.

**Expected Output File Description:**

A CSV file named "stock.csv" containing the first column as SYMBOL, with HINDUNILVR as the entry in each cell of that column, followed by the many prices and details associated with the stock for each and every day, in the same row.

**Python Code:**

```
if(int(str(sdate.day))<10):

     df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open("cm" + "0" + str(sdate.day) + MonthCode(sdate.month) + str(sdate.year) + "bhav.csv"))

   else:

     df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open("cm" + str(sdate.day) + MonthCode(sdate.month) + str(sdate.year) + "bhav.csv"))

   df2 = df1.set_index("SYMBOL", drop = False)

   saved_row = df2.loc["HINDUNILVR",:]

      with open_file('C:\stock.csv','a') as f:
        saved_row.to_csv(f,header=False)
```

Comment: Is your script running with right privileges to write to c drive?

Comment: if don't have write privileges code will throw exception

Comment: i have changed the code to:                                                                                                              
                                                                                                         
 with open_file(r'''C:\Users\Mukund\Documents\stock.csv''','a') as f:
      saved_row.to_csv(f,mode='a',header=False) , still it is an empty output, turns out I didn't have privileges to write to C drive

Comment: if u didn't have privileges to write to C:\ Drive didn't the code throw exception with permission denied error. Can you post the sample file.

Comment: There was no exception thrown. What do you mean by sample file? The file of expected output?

Comment: This is how the expected output should look, (just one line has been done by me for sample):                                                                                      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dB7II4ItF-p4lwthEwoHYkL2g5Co6X-v/view?usp=sharing

Comment: zip file which contains the source CSV.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i5xlCLAUNWHjzBvjBETza3W_r7aa28k4/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                   this is one of the zip files ( the one corresponding to the output file posted earlier)

Comment: Please check solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you simply want all rows where `SYMBOL='HINDUNILVR'` to be copied to a new file. 
Below Sample code read the same file and write back to the same file. You can change the file name as required:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df1 = pd.read_csv("Sample.csv")
df2 = df1[df1["SYMBOL"]=="HINDUNILVR"]
with open('Sample.csv','a+') as f:
    df2.to_csv(f,header=False,index=False)
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df1 = pd.read_csv("Sample.csv")
df2 = df1[df1["SYMBOL"]=="HINDUNILVR"]
df2.to_csv("Sample.csv",header=False,mode='a+',index=False)
```

or an Update on your code :

```
 if(int(str(sdate.day))<10):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open("cm" + "0" + str(sdate.day) + MonthCode(sdate.month) + str(sdate.year) + "bhav.csv"))
else:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open("cm" + str(sdate.day) + MonthCode(sdate.month) + str(sdate.year) + "bhav.csv"))
df2 = df1[df1["SYMBOL"]=="HINDUNILVR"]
df2.to_csv("C:\stock.csv",mode='a+',header=False,index=False)
```

or

```
    if(int(str(sdate.day))<10):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open("cm" + "0" + str(sdate.day) + MonthCode(sdate.month) + str(sdate.year) + "bhav.csv"))
else:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open("cm" + str(sdate.day) + MonthCode(sdate.month) + str(sdate.year) + "bhav.csv"))
df2 = df1[df1["SYMBOL"]=="HINDUNILVR"]
with open('C:\stock.csv','a+') as f:
    df2.to_csv(f,header=False,index=False)
```

Comment: You can try with below as well: 
        `saved_row.to_csv(f,mode='a',header=False)`
default is 'w' but very difficult without sample file.

Comment: `a+`  in case file does not exist it will create file.

Comment: shouldn't it be : df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open("data.csv")), where data.csv is located within the zip file, and Sample.csv is where we want to store the data

Comment: I mentioned you can change the file name as required. I have updated above as per your code as well.

Comment: if this is correct as per your requirement please accept the solution.

Comment: Still I am not getting the required output, you haven't changed my code in any way in your updates

Comment: Thank You so much, it is working now, there was another error elsewhere that I also had to fix.

Comment: Cheers, always Welcome